# SQLite how to get same groups by id?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a question about query. Here is my table:

[image]

I get id by onClick method and I want result like this. For example if id is 2 get all rows who has same group.

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.group = (select t2.group from mytable t2 where t2.id = 2);
```

Note that `group` is a really bad name for a column, because it is a SQL keyword.  It is fine for illustration.